# jmeter-graph-maven-plugin types of graphs available?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am writing a JMeter suite to run on top of Jenkins and generating charts using the **jmeter-graph-maven-plugin**.

The tests are being executed with the **jmeter-maven-plugin** and generating the corresponding *.jtl files that the jmeter-graph plugin expects.

I would like to know all the types of graphs that can be generated through **jmeter-graph-maven-plugin** when I declare them on the pom.xml as such:

```
<graph>
    <pluginType>ThreadsStateOverTime</pluginType>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
    <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/ThreadsStateOverTime.png</outputFile>
</graph>
```

Is there a comprehensive list of all possible  entries I could use?

Thanks,

Neill

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on this documentation:

- http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/

You can generate:

- ThreadsStateOverTime = Active Threads Over Time
- BytesThroughputOverTime
- HitsPerSecond
- LatenciesOverTime
- ResponseCodesPerSecond
- ResponseTimesDistribution
- ResponseTimesOverTime
- ResponseTimesPercentiles
- ThroughputVsThreads
- TimesVsThreads = Response Times VS Threads
- TransactionsPerSecond

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks a lot!